# Spark Dataframe - Schema file definition

Tags: java, apache-spark, schema, parquet

I have a simple Spark application which aims to read delimited text files and save them as parquet format.

The requirement is to process a flat data file (without header) which will be accompanied by a schema definition.   End result is an executable jar which is passed these as command line arguments.

Examples I have reviewed so far either look to infer the schema from the header row or to define the schema within the code itself.   How could this be achieved?

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;


public class SparkCSVApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("JavaWordCount").setMaster("local");
    // create Spark Context
    SparkContext context = new SparkContext(conf);
    // create spark Session
    SparkSession sparkSession = new SparkSession(context);

    Dataset<Row> df = sparkSession
            .read()
            .format("com.databricks.spark.csv")
            .option("header", true)
            .option("inferSchema", true)
            .load("/Users/Chris/Desktop/Meter_Geocode_Data_150215_114551.csv"); //TODO: CMD line arg
                        //("hdfs://localhost:9000/usr/local/hadoop_data/loan_100.csv");

    System.out.println("========== Print Schema ============");
    df.printSchema();
    System.out.println("========== Print Data ==============");
    df.show();
    System.out.println("========== Generate parquet file ==============");
    df.write().parquet("/Users/Chris/Desktop/meter_geocode.parquet");

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`inferSchema` doesnt figure out data types from header row.It figures out datatypes from data itself, here is text from documentation -

> inferSchema – infers the input **schema automatically from data**. It
>   requires one extra pass over the data. If None is set, it uses the
>   default value, false.

Edit :

To associate schema defined in some other file to existing dataframe, there are few ways you can do it programatically.

Suppose, you have data in `main.csv` and all the headers in 2nd file called `header.csv` which just contain comma separated list of column names. Do following -

```
# read main data file, 
df = spark.read.csv("main.csv",header=False,inferSchema=True)

# read the file where headers are stored as string
hrdd = sc.textFile("header.csv")    
# make a list
newColumns = hrdd.collect()[0].split(",")

# Method # 1 : renaming all columns one by one 

# first get old column names
oldColumns = df.columns

if len(oldColumns) == len(newColumns):
    for i,newCol in enumerate(newColumns):
        df = df.withColumnRenamed(oldColumns[i],newCol)


or
# Method # 2 : just create a new dataframe by passing schema which was derived from reading 2nd file.

df = spark.createDataFrame(df.rdd,schema=newColumns)
```

Disclaimer: this is written in pyspark , I am sure its simple enough in java too.

Comment: Yep, understand this.   But how do I associate data columns to a header via a schema definition file?  So that any dataset could be processed?

Comment: @chris-finlayson added new answer